# Connecting Windows C# Web Service to Hadoop Database installed on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, hadoop

I'm supposed to connect a .NET web service I created to a remote Hadoop database installed on a Linux machine. However, given that the Web service is on Windows, and I'm very new at this, never connected to a remote database, much less one that was located on a machine with another OS, is it possible to do this. I've heard of an ODBC driver called Microsoft HiveODBC, it seems to me like that is my best bet. I know connecting to a server on another OS shouldn't be an issue since the driver, or web service will act as intermediary.

However, is this possible, I assume someone must have done it, all I need are some specifics on how it works, if Microsoft HiveODBC works for this and if not, what else I could use. I'm also going to have to do the opposite later, but instead I'm going to have to connect from linux to an SQL Server Database.

If anyone knows anything, any guide or any sort of specifics, then I'd appreciate if they could help me. Also switching C#, or SQL Server for something else is not possible, otherwise I'd have just gone with Linux alone.

Comment: HiveODBC works perfectly for such scenarios.

Comment: Well that's good then, hopefully this will go smoothly then.

Comment: refer to to the following link for more info http://hortonworks.com/blog/hadoop-sdk-and-tutorials-for-microsoft-net-developers/

Comment: I see, thanks for the help.